# How add shortcuts into icon dock java

Tags: java, swing, icons, awt, jbutton

is it possible to add some links to functions like native applications into java icon dock in windows, macOS and linux? For example google chrome has "New window", "New Incognito Window"...
I'm using java swing and awt.

[image: Example of links]

Comment: For MacOS, you could have a look at [`com.apple.eawt.Application`](https://coderanch.com/how-to/javadoc/appledoc/api/com/apple/eawt/Application.html), the docs are hard to come by, but should give you some kind of entry point